# Access static property from array params

Tags: typescript

I need to have array of classes and then be able to iterate over that array and access this classes stratic property:

```
class Blah{
    static type: string = "blah";
}

class Foo{
    blahs: Array<{new(): Blah}>
    go(){
        this.blahs.map(function(blah){
            console.log(blah.type);
        })
    }
}
```

this example will result in error:

> Property 'type' does not exist on type `new()=>Blah`

I need it to be array since all this classes are classes for components for game entity and each entity may have different set of components, but only one component of each type. So I make type a static property to be able check if such component already added to game object, without creating instance of that component class.

so how can I rewrite this code?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can have it like this:

```
class Blah
{
    static type: string = "blah";
}

class Foo
{
    blahs: Array<Blah>
    go()
    {
        this.blahs.map(function(blah)
        {
            console.log(Blah.type);
        })
    }
}
```

But this makes no sense to me because value of the static property 'type' will be shared among all instances of the class. So your console.log will write the same value for every object.

So either consider making 'type' non static or think about reworking your classes structure.

[EDIT]

If you have a need to iterate over set of different classes and print out their 'type' static property (considering all of them has one), then it can be done this way.

Declare separate module file with all such classes:

Blahs.ts:

```
export class Blah0
{
    static type: string = "blah";
}

export class Blah1
{
    static type: string = "blah";
}

export class Blah2
{
    static type: string = "blah";
}
```

Then in your app.ts:

```
import * as Blahs from 'Blahs';

class Foo
{
    go()
    {
        Object.keys(Blahs).forEach(className => 
        {
            console.log(Blahs[className].type);
        });
    }
}

let f = new Foo();
f.go();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanx for you response. I will have a bunch of classes inherited from Blah with different `type` value and in any moment of time I will not have any knowledge about what classes are in `blahs` array so I can`t use none of your variants.

Comment: 'Blahs' is not an array. We can say its module with classes defined in it. If you can get reference to it - you do not need to have any knowledge about it contents and the code will work.

Comment: I need it to be array since all this classes are classes for components for game entity and each entity may have different set of components, but only one component of each type. So I make type a static property to be able check if such component already added to game object, without creating instance of that component class.